# How pow function works in this case?

Tags: c, pow, math.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int i = 11;
printf("%d ^ 2 = %d\n",i,(int)pow(i,2));
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

In this case instead of getting 121,i am getting 120.What is the mistake i am making?
(I really need to print pow(i,2) as an int.)

Comment: Why use floating point `math.h` if you need `int` arithmetics?

Comment: I get 121. How did you get 120?

Comment: Although there are, _in general_, potential rounding issues, a decent `pow()` would return the expected 121.  OP has a  [Schlocky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schlock) math library.

Answer (score 5):

Casting to integer truncates the fraction, possibly `pow` returned something like 120.99999998 or so...

Don't cast to `(int)` and use %g format instead of %d to print `double` result of `pow()`.

Comment: On gcc 4.1.2, I still get 121 with those changes. Not sure what compiler OP is using

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with rounding from double to int.

As the power is constant why have the overhead.

Stick to

```
printf("%d ^ 2 = %d\n",i, i*i);
```